# Cannot Assign Elements to Dynamically Allocated Two Dimensional Array in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, dynamic

Hope everyone is doing well.

I am trying to write a simple Matrix Library in C by creating a Matrix struct, and then using its memory address to execute operations.

Here is my header file for the library:

```
/*
To compile:

g++ -c simpMat.cpp
ar rvs simpMat.a simpMat.o
g++ test_simpMat.c simpMat.a
*/

#ifndef SIMPMATH_H
#define SIMPMAT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
    uint8_t nRows;
    uint8_t nCols;
    uint8_t nElements;
    float **elements;
}simpMat;

/**
*@brief simpMat_Init
*@param simpMat
*@param uint8_t
*@param uint8_t
*@param uint8_t
*@param float* 
*@retval NONE
*/
void simpMat_Init(simpMat *Matrix, uint8_t nRows, uint8_t nColumns, uint8_t nElements, float elements[]);

/**
*@brief simpMat_Print
*@param simpMat
*@retval NONE
*/
void simpMat_Print(simpMat *Matrix);

/**
*@brief simpMat_Delete
*@param simpMat
*@retval NONE
*/
void simpMat_Delete(simpMat *Matrix);

#endif
```

Here is the source file:

```
#include "simpMat.h"

void simpMat_Init(simpMat *Matrix, uint8_t nRows, uint8_t nColumns, uint8_t nElements, float elements[])
{
    Matrix->nRows = nRows;
    Matrix->nCols = nColumns;
    Matrix->nElements = nElements;

    Matrix->elements = (float**)malloc(nRows * sizeof(float*));
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        Matrix->elements[i] = (float*)malloc(nColumns * sizeof(float));
    }
    
    uint8_t count = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
        {
            Matrix->elements[i][j] = elements[count];
            count++;
        }
    }      
        
}

void simpMat_Print(simpMat *Matrix)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < Matrix->nRows; i++)
    {
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < Matrix->nCols; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", Matrix->elements[i][j]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}


void simpMat_Delete(simpMat *Matrix)
{
    uint8_t n = Matrix->nRows;
    while(n) free(Matrix->elements[--n]);
    free(Matrix->elements);
}
```

I also wrote a small test program to see if I can successfully assign elements to the matrix; such as:

```
#include "simpMat.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    simpMat Matrix1;

    float toAppend[9] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};

    simpMat_Init(&Matrix1, 3, 2, 9, toAppend);

    printf("MATRIX ELEMENTS ARE:\n");

    simpMat_Print(&Matrix1);

    simpMat_Delete(&Matrix1);

    return 0;

}
```

I compiled my library and the main program with the following commands on CMD:

```
g++ -c simpMat.cpp
ar rvs simpMat.a simpMat.o
g++ test_simpMat.c simpMat.a
```

However, when I run the executable, I get the following output:

```
MATRIX ELEMENTS ARE:
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

I could not understand the reason I cannot assign values. I am fairly new to the Dynamic Memory Allocation subject and I suspect that I had a misconception about the methodology. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a debugger and step through your program looking at the memory, you should see the data *is* actually there.  Your question assumes the problem is assignment, whereas it's actually in your output.  This kind of thing is most easily discoverable with a debugger.

The actual problem is your matrix elements are `float`.  But you are using `%d` specifier in your `printf`, which is for `int` values.  Change this to `%f`.

Separately, you should reconsider the purpose of the `nElements` parameter.  You are not doing any sanity tests before copying the array (for example, ensuring `rows * cols` does not exceed that value).  It doesn't appear to have any relation to the actual matrix and should not be stored.

Comment: I am cursing myself now. Thank you so much!

You are right about the nElements parameter. I was planning to use it to check the dimensions of the source array but have not implemented it yet.

Comment: @kucar You could probably check the dimensions with `rows/columns`, so `nElements` isn't needed and may make the code more fragile because you're doing an array of pointers to rows. And, given that, a bit of  a moot point, but `uint8_t` may be too small. If you _do_ end up needing it, I'd use `uint32_t` for the case where the number of elements is >= 256. Might also use `uint32_t` for rows/cols as well.